# Proving that uniformly continuous functions respect Cauchy sequences in their domain

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I'm having a hard time coming up with a valid Cauchy sequence that fits this criteria. I am unsure of a solid approach to determine such a Cauchy sequence, besides trial and error with something that appears to affect $\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$.

> Let $A = (0, \infty)$. The function $f(x) = \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ is continuous on $A$. Show that for this function $f$ there is a Cauchy sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ in its domain such that $\{f(x_{n})\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Remember that in $\mathbb{R}$ a sequence is cauchy iff it is convergent. Also, if $f$ is continuous function defined on each point of a sequence, and its limit, then $\lim f(x_n) = f(x)$, so, you need a sequence in $A$, which is Cauchy, but that *does not converge in $A$*.

Comment: @James $a_{n} = \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: That's an example of such a sequence, can you also show that $f(a_n)$ is not Cauchy?

Comment: Hmm, $f(a_{n})$ just becomes $\sin{n}$, which evidently isn't convergent but isn't immediately clear as to how to show that.

Comment: Indeed, showing that it isn't convergent would be a bother, although it is true that that sequence does not converge. So, you can try to modify your sequence a little so that it still converges to 0, but the sine of its reciprocals are more easy to calculate. Below is a good example.

Comment: @James Cheers, I made another one just for fun. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_n = \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi}$ then $x_n $ is Cauchy sequence but $f(x_n )=(-1)^n $ is not.